# Сформировать JSON, исходя из переданного query-параметра

Tags: java, json, rest, микросервисы

Всем привет.

Допустим, у нас имеется класс:

```
public class User {

private String username;
private String ipAddress;
private String phone;

//+ getter'ы и setter'ы

}
```

Допустим, мне приходит запрос с одним параметром, где перечислены поля, которые 
необходимо будет отдать на выходе, например:

```
http://host:port/api/result=username,phone
```

То есть необходимо сформировать JSON-объект User, только по полям username и phone, игнорируя ipAddress. По сути, result является в итоге строкой. Не вижу вариантов, кроме как парсить строку, сравнивать с названием каждого параметра и, если совпадают, то добавлять в JSON.

Из этого следует вопрос, может быть есть какие-нибудь библиотеки для таких случаев или еще что ?

Использую Gson для формирования JSON и Jersey для Rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `Gson` для формирования `Json`. Я полагаю, что вы помещаете запрашиваемые поля в массив или список, таким образом можно легко использовать [ExclusionStrategy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html). Реализовав этот интерфейс, вы сможете пропускать ненужные поля при формировании `Json`.

Приведу пример. Использовал [Gson 2.8.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5).

```
      public class Person {
        private String username;
        private transient  String ipAddress;
        private String phone;

        public Person(String username, String ipAddress, String phone) {
            this.username = username;
            this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
            this.phone = phone;
        }

    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Person person0 = new Person("Andrew", "192.168.0.1", "88005553535");
        Person person1 = new Person("Victor", "192.168.0.1", "88005553535");
        Person person2 = new Person("Alex", "192.168.0.1", "88005553535");

        Person[] persons = {person0, person1, person2};

        List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        fieldNames.add("username");
        fieldNames.add("phone");

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return !fieldNames.contains(f.getName());            
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();

        String json = gson.toJson(persons);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

Вывод: `[{"username":"Andrew","phone":"88005553535"},{"username":"Victor","phone":"88005553535"},{"username":"Alex","phone":"88005553535"}]`

Либо можете дополнительно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909205/java-gson-exclude-fields-during-serialization/40913991)